# OpenWrt logging: how to find out "wifi deauthentication"

Tags: linux, logging, openwrt

If someone starts to use the wifi, i can see that with logread:

`Jan 23 21:04:47 router daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX IEEE 802.11: authenticated`

But how can i see, that he/she's disconnecting? Theres no "bla-bla deauthenticated bla" line in logread, or even a thing that points to that someone get's disconnected..

I tried to google:
http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/system
But it doesn't writes about loglevel.

Can anyone help me find out, how to find out that someone disconnects it's wifi from the router? The logread doesn't even writes a line when someone disconnects.

Please help!! It's important!
Thank you!:\

Answer (score 1):

```
config wifi-device 'radio0'
        option log_level '0'
```

... works at least in openwrt trunk (as of today).

To check:

```
grep log /var/run/hostapd*conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Try edit /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf:

```
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=0
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=0
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=e1Sa65fc

Answer (score 0):

I see lines like this in my log file which at least indicate there's been no activity:

```
Aug  1 16:31:25 OpenWrt1 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA f8:1e:00:00:00:00 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
Aug  1 16:31:26 OpenWrt1 daemon.info hostapd: wlan0: STA f8:1e:00:00:00:00 IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to inactivity
```